# "polls.apps.PollsConfig" and "polls" in `INSTALLED APPS'

Tags: django

To tell Django which apps are installed, the official documentation introduces

```
The advantage 'polls.apps.PollsConfig'  over 'polls'

setting.py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
   #my APPs
    "polls.apps.PollsConfig",
]
```

This explicitly refer to the installed app in `app.py`

```
from django.apps import AppConfig
class LearningLogsConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'learning_logs'
```

However, in some books, it tell it in a shortcut

```
setting.py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
   #my APPs
    "polls",
]
```

How Django access 'polls' in this situation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Django can use either option. The version with the `AppConfig` lets you point Django specifically to [an application configuration class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/applications/#application-configuration) which lets you specify some additional config for the app.

If you just want the app as-is, refer to it by its name alone. Use the `AppConfig` variant *only* when you are supplying an `AppConfig` class to configure something about the application.

Answer (score 0):

In the manage.py location Django will check with the string you have given in installed apps list.

Each string should be a dotted Python path to:

- an application configuration class (preferred), or
- a package containing an application.